# "Else" statement not responding

Tags: python, if-statement

I wrote a software that should respond to an input of an user, however

the `if` statement doesn't return `else`

````
print("#" * 9)

Commands that you can use:
-------------------------
1. Theme A – Home and abroad
1.1 Life in the town and rural life
1.2 
""")
question = input("Topic: ")

RuralLife = """
 Theme A – Home and abroad

"""

if question == "Theme A – Home and abroad" or "Life in the town and rural life":
    print(RuralLife)
else:
    print("Please Select Topic")```
````

Comment: This does not look like proper Python code (see PEP8) also the question could use some more info. What do you mean by not responding to an else statement?

Comment: also why do you have three backticks (`) in the end of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if question == "Theme A – Home and abroad" or "Life in the town and rural life"` will **always** be true, because it's evaluated like this :

```
#                  boolean                   or                 boolean
if (question == "Theme A – Home and abroad") or ("Life in the town and rural life")
```

The first boolean `(question == "Theme A – Home and abroad")` will be true or false depending of the value of `question`.

The second `"Life in the town and rural life"` will **always** be true since a string is not a [falsy value](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

`something_true_or_false or true == true`

Change your condition to :

```
# Check this ---------------------------------v----------v
if question == "Theme A – Home and abroad" or question == "Life in the town and rural life"
```

Comment: Thank you very much guys! Im new to stack and new to Python programming , so therefore sometimes might give stupid questions :D anyways it worked

Comment: so what was the problem itself?

Comment: @SpoOkYyAmbassador I explained it in the answer, is there any part you don't understand and I could clarify ?

Comment: You might want to read about "[Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)" in the current documentation.

Comment: ive used the last one: "if question == "Theme A – Home and abroad" or question == "Life in the town and rural life" and it worked like magic, but when i added same thing , it strikes right to else statement now whenever i call the 2nd statement

if question == "Theme A – Home and abroad" or question == "Life in the town and rural life":
    print(RuralLife)
else:
    print("Please Select Topic")

if question == "Theme B – Education and employment" or question == "School life and routine":
    print(Theme)
else: print()

here when i call out Theme B it goes to else

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below, the issue is with the or condition

```
print("#" * 9)

print("""
Commands that you can use:
-------------------------
1. Theme A – Home and abroad
1.1 Life in the town and rural life
1.2 
""")

question = input("Topic: ")

RuralLife = """
 Theme A – Home and abroad

"""

if question == "Theme A – Home and abroad" or question == "Life in the town and rural life":
    print(RuralLife)
else:
    print("Please Select Topic")
```

Or you can write the if condition like this

```
if question in ("Theme A – Home and abroad", "Life in the town and rural life"):
    print(RuralLife)
else:
    print("Please Select Topic")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in your if statement.

```py
if question == "Theme A – Home and abroad" or "Life in the town and rural life":
```

is interpreted as

```py
if (question == "Theme A – Home and abroad") or "Life in the town and rural life":
```

And in python, a string that is not empty evaluates to True.

You can fix it by replacing your if condition by

```py
if question in ("Theme A – Home and abroad", "Life in the town and rural life"):
```